# Шифрование 3des-cbc в SSH

Tags: криптография

Здравствуйте! Сейчас я работаю над реализацией SSH протокола на C++. Разбираюсь с cbc модом шифрования. Я понял, что начальный вектор инициализации для первого блока шифрованного пакета вычисляется из хэша определенных данных, вектор инициализации для последующих блоков - это предыдущего блока шифротекста. Это все работает только для первого пакета, во втором пакете расшифровать первый блок не получается. Возможно потому, что последний блок шифротекста первого пакета состоит из 4 байт? Каким образом вычисляется начальный IV для второго пакета?

Answer (score 1):

"начальный вектор инициализации для первого блока шифрованного пакета вычисляется из хэша определенных данных" - не так. IV передается в криптоалгоритм как есть, никаких его преобразований алгоритм не производит.
"вектор инициализации для последующих блоков - это предыдущего блока шифротекста" - это результат шифрования предыдущего блока. Без хэширования и так далее.
"последний блок шифротекста первого пакета состоит из 4 байт" - добавляйте padding, при расшифровке - удаляйте.
И да, не стоит самому писать криптографию, когда есть OpenSSL...